# Randomly scheduled tasks and celery

Tags: django, celery

Everyday I have a set of tasks (A few hundred) that needs to performed at random time. So a periodic task is probably not what I want. It seems like I cannot dynamically change crontab

Should I:

Dynamically schedule a task whenever it's received a user, and let celery "wake up" at the scheduled time to perform the task? If so, how is it done?

OR

Create a celery tasks that wakes up every 60 seconds to look into the database for tasks scheduled current time. So the database acts as a queue. I am wondering if this would put too much load on the server?